# How to copy from an app like a browser into Emacs over existing text?

Tags: emacs, clipboard

I am trying to copy some text from the browser by highlighting it. I then go to emacs and want to paste over an existing paragraph without deleting it beforehand. How do you do that?

Comment: This would be on topic in the Emacs Stack Exchange. Just FYI.

Answer (score 3):

According to Michael Mrozek in *[How to replace a region in emacs with yank buffer contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627298/4518274)*

> Add this to your .emacs:

```
(delete-selection-mode 1)
```

> Anything that writes to the buffer while the region is active will overwrite it, including paste, but also simply typing something or hitting backspace

Further reading:

- [12.3.1 Using the Clipboard](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html) (GNU Emacs Manual)
- [In Emacs why can I not paste text C-y into a C-s search box?](https://superuser.com/questions/221829/in-emacs-why-can-i-not-paste-text-c-y-into-a-c-s-search-box)

Answer (score 0):

Emacs doesn't have an "overwrite current selection" command, but you can easily (hah!) write your own.